# Class Not Found Exception but it is in the same package

Tags: java, firebase, servlets, firebase-realtime-database, classnotfoundexception

So I have a class called DataGrabber that uses the Java Wrapper for Firebase to get data from my Firebase DB. I included the dependencies and all the java classes are in the same package so they should all have access to each other.

However, there is a ClassNotFoundException thrown where
    `firebase = new Firebase(String url);`

```
public class DataGrabber {

    Firebase firebase;
    FirebaseResponse response;

    public DataGrabber(String url) {
        try {
            firebase = new Firebase(url);
        } catch (FirebaseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

[Here is the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srtRn.png)

Comment: Read the error, it is saying that HttpRequestBase is not found

Comment: @ScaryWombat Im so sorry I totally misread the error

Comment: Note that your use of `Firebase` seems to indicate that you're using a *really* old version of the Firebase SDK. I *highly* recommend that you upgrade to a more recent version: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to the above error, for dependencies it isn't enough to simply reference them in your library, but you need to import them to your WEB-INF/lib!